# What is the meaning of this statement? $\{x\in\mathbb R^3 \mid Ax=0\}=\{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the exact meaning of this phrase?  My book doesn't bother explaining it, but I know that I have a linearly dependent system, so this isn't a valid statement:

$$\{x\in\mathbb R^3 \mid Ax=0\}=\{0\}$$

Thanks!

Comment: Is my edit what you intended?

Comment: Yes!  That's exactly it!  Thank you!

Comment: It states the Kernal of $A$ is trivial (just contains the zero vector). I imagine from what you wrote that it's a typo and inequality was meant.

Comment: what system would that be, exactly?

Comment: @DavidMitra : I changed $\{\bullet|\bullet\}$ to $\{\bullet\mid\bullet\}$ (that makes proper spacing automatic).

Comment: The system is: $[0, -1, -1; 0, 2, 2; -1, 1, 2]$  all three equations set to zero.  I come up with a linearly dependent system with infinite solutions.  David, this was copied directly from the assignment.

Comment: As written, the statement means "the only solution to $A\vec{x} = \vec{0}$ is the trivial solution."  But, since it is a dependent system, the author has made a typo...

Answer (score 1):

If the only vector of $\mathbb{R}^3$ in the nullspace of $A$ is the zero vector (which is the case here), then the matrix is of full rank. This implies the rows (or columns) are linearly independent.

Comment: You may want to add that this means that the function that sends $x$ to $Ax$ is injective. Also, the comment that the *rows* are linearly independent only applies if we know that $A$ is a square matrix.

Comment: We don't know anything about the dimension of the matrix. It is of full rank, so whichever is smaller, the number of rows or the number of columns, will be the linearly independent set. That is why I said rows or columns.

Comment: You have that the columns are independent; this means that there are at least $3$ rows, and that among the rows, there are three that are independent, but there are no $4$ that are independent.

Comment: Good point. I overlooked the extra information that $A$ acts on a 3-dimensional vector.